# How to remove a node while preserving its value and child nodes?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an XML like this:

```
<root>
<parent1>Some random <child1>text </child1>here. And a random <child2>image </child2>here.</parent1>
</root>
```

And want to have this:

```
<root>Some random <child1>text </child1>here. And a random <child2>image </child2>here.</root>
```

Before I used this:

```
foreach (var p in doc.Descendants("parent1"))
    p.ReplaceWith(p.Value);
```

Which resulted in:

```
<root>Some random text here. And a random image here.</root>
```

But now I have to preserve the child nodes.

Comment: It is better to use XSLT for the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new `XElement` with the same name (`root`)  and include the nodes of its first element (`parent`).

```
const string Xml = @"
    <root>
        <parent1>Some random <child1>text </child1>here. And a random <child2>image </child2>here.</parent1>
    </root>";
var xml = XElement.Parse(Xml);

var result = new XElement(
    xml.Name,
    xml.Elements().First().Nodes()
    );

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

---

I you prefer a replace, then replace that first element with its nodes.
Note that this affects the original `xml` `XElement`.

```
var first = xml.Elements().First();
first.ReplaceWith(first.Nodes());

Console.WriteLine(xml);
```